# UWP PrintPageRangeOptions.AllowCustomSetOfPages Property not working

Tags: uwp

I'm creating a print task (it's been a while since I initially put this together but I believe I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) example). The dialog appears and prints just fine, but I've decided that I would like to add the option to print a custom set of pages.

To do that, I set the AllowCustomSetOfPages property to true, but there's no difference in the outcome (dialog appears and prints, but there's not option to select a custom set of pages).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP PrintPageRangeOptions.AllowCustomSetOfPages Property not working

Please check this official print [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Printing/cs/Scenario4PageRange.xaml.cs#L70). If you set `AllowCustomSetOfPages` as true. you will get the option in the options combobox  as the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Gotcha.  I'm not able to make the sample work as is, but it gives me plenty to look at.  It's enough to make me say you answered my question (the answer being that I was missing a lot).  Thanks!